# Why is my mapView (GMSMapView) nil?

Tags: ios, swift

can someone please help me?
I'm segueing from one view (verifyCode) to another view (mainMap). When i segue to the mainMap i receive an error saying that the mapView is nil. Why is this happening?

Here's some of the code:
mainMapController

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 38.96351774, longitude:-77.01957901, zoom: 15.0)
    mapVIEW.camera = camera <-------- it errors on this line.
}
```

verifyCodeController :

```
if code == codeField.text{
        numberInUse(number: phoneNumber!, completionHandler: { (Value) in
            if Value == true{
                print("toMap segue")
                print(Value)
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "nextMap", sender: nil)
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map-with-marker) shows how to initialise the map

```
// Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
// coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
view = mapView
```

Theres nothing in your code to suggest you've actually initialised it

You at least need to call

```
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
```

UPDATE:

Make sure that you set your API key on App Startup:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOUR_API_KEY")
    return true
}
```

Comment: I changed it to this, but now the map screen is just black. Do you possibly have any ideas why this could be?                                                               let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 38.96351774, longitude:-77.01957901, zoom: 15.0)
        let mView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
                                                                                                               mapView = mView

Comment: If i run the sample code I'm also getting blank tiles at the moment. I'll look into it, are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I updated the answer with what fixed my sample project